# Multiple class java simulation

Tags: java

I've written a class to simulate a gravitational field, and a main class that uses it. I'm sure my equations are right, but while the code compiles, when I run it it returns 'NaN'. This is the first time I've used multiple classes, so I just wondered if I'm linking them correctly:
Here's my GravField class:

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class GravField{

    public static final double G = 6.674*Math.pow(10,-11);      //defines the constant G    
    private double planetMass;                      
    private double planetRadius;                        
    private double projectileX;
    private double projectileY;
    private double a = planetRadius + projectileY;  

    PhysicsVector projectilePosition = new PhysicsVector(projectileX, a);   //PhysicsVector class was written
    PhysicsVector gravityAcceleration = new PhysicsVector();        //lecturer, so that won't be the problem!

    public GravField(double planetMass, double planetRadius, double projectileX, double projectileY){

        double distance = Math.sqrt(projectileX*projectileX+projectileY*projectileY);               

        double x = (-G*planetMass*projectileX)/(distance*distance*distance);    
        double y = (-G*planetMass*a)/(distance*distance*distance);

        gravityAcceleration.setVector(x, y);        //setVector is a method in the PhysicsVector class      
        gravityAcceleration.print();            //print is also in PhysicsVector
    }

    public double magnitude(){
        double magnitudeOfGravField = gravityAcceleration.magnitude();  
        return magnitudeOfGravField;
    }

    public double componentX(){

        double xComponent = gravityAcceleration.getX();     //gravityAcceleration for some reason can't be 
        return xComponent;                  //directly accessed by main class, so use this instead
    }

    public double componentY(){
        double yComponent = gravityAcceleration.getY();
        return yComponent;
    }
}
```

Then in my main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class ParticleSim{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the size of the time step:");
        double timeStep = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the initial x velocity:");
        double initialXVelocity = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the initial y velocity:");
        double initialYVelocity = scanner.nextDouble();

        PhysicsVector projectilePosition = new PhysicsVector();

        double earthMass = 5.972*Math.pow(10,24);
        double earthRadius = 6371000;

        GravField earth = new GravField(earthMass, earthRadius, 0, 0);

        double y=0.0;
        double x=0.0;
        double yVelocity=initialYVelocity;
        double xVelocity=initialXVelocity;

        do{                 //either this loop or my GravField class is the problem, I think!
            System.out.println("Hi! I'm in the loop!");
            y += yVelocity * timeStep;      //Euler's algorithm to calculate positions and velocities
            x += xVelocity*timeStep;
            yVelocity += earth.componentY() * timeStep;     
            xVelocity += earth.componentX() * timeStep;

            PhysicsVector velocity = new PhysicsVector();
            PhysicsVector position = new PhysicsVector();
            velocity.setVector(xVelocity, yVelocity);
            position.setVector(x, y);

            velocity.print();
            position.print();

            timeStep += timeStep;
        }while(y>0);
    }
}
```

Is it right that every GravField object will have a variable gravityAcceleration? And that by writing earth.componentY() I'm asking for the Y component of gravityAcceleration for earth?
If you manage to wade through my code I really appreciate it! Thanks for any help!

Comment: you pass in 0 for projectileX and projecttimeY to GravField constructor, which based on your equation (check operator precedence), will result in distance being 0, after which you divide by distance^3, which is 0.

Comment: @DBug Oh dear... really should have seen that. Thanks, that was so quick! But what if I want to start at the origin? Does that mean my equations are wrong, if they can't handle that?

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed calling for gravityAcceleration's x by calling earth.componentx()
but I think the flaw is putting your logic around

```
double distance = Math.sqrt(projectileX*projectileX+projectileY*projectileY);               
double x = (-G*planetMass*projectileX)/(distance*distance*distance);    
double y = (-G*planetMass*a)/(distance*distance*distance);
```

Inside of the constructor of GravField. this is only being called once when you create earth. So earth starts with a gravityAcceleration with 0 x and 0 y, and that never changes.

you'll need to move things around so that it happens in the loop, and you can recalculate distance and the projectile's vector each step.

Comment: Inside a loop and still in the constructor? Or outside the loop? That's so complicated! The changing projectileX will be calculated by main though! How do I get GravField to use it?

Comment: currently projectileX never changes, it is passed in when earth is created, but never saved to a value. Just because the variable name of the parameter is the same as the field in the class doesn't make them match.
You could store them by doing this.projectileX  = projectileX ;
or you can maek a new method to do the calculation ie:
`getGravAccelVector(posX, posY, velocityX, velocityY){
// distance and other calcuations, using the passed in x and y
// return gravAccel vector
}`
and call that in the loop

Answer (score 0):

No, GravField itself will not have a variable gravityAccerlation as it’s defined inside of PhysicsVector, however, you can access it by using, for example, projectilePosition.gravityAcceleration;

When you call earth.componentY() you are accessing the PhysicsVector’s value of Y and assigning it to GravField's Y component, so, you are indeed getting the Y component of earth.

Inside the ParticleSim class you never can begin the loop due to the (y>0) condition, as you have defined y as being equal to 0.

Comment: But it's a do-while loop, I thought it would run it at least once. And running through it the first time would give y a non-zero value, so it would then continue? I thought?

Comment: My apologies, I misread it. You are correct.

When you pass 0 to the constructor in your ParticleSim class it instantiates the projectileX and projectileY values to 0 inside the GravField class, and when you do your math operations inside of the constructor it attempts to divide 0.0 by 0.0, which results in the NaN (not a number) error since you are setting these values to the PhysicsVector values and then attempting to print it out.